# Ubuntu 12.04 VPN does not connect

Tags: 12.04, vpn, pptp, pptpd

I try to use `VPN` on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS 32 bit but it fails and gives the message that the `VPN` service failed to start. How can I resolve this issue?

Edit: The connection type is `PPTP` and I use the credentials provided on [VPNbook](http://www.vpnbook.com)

P.S: I try to connect to a preconfigured VPN that used to work fine through the `GUI` network manager.

Comment: What VPN connection? l2tp, pptp, openvpn, other?<br/>
What configuration have you used?

Comment: I have used `pptp` connection with the settings (account credentials) taken from the website: www.vpnbook.com

Answer (score 1):

After I read something about `openconnect` possibly being related to this kind of issue, I launched `Synaptic Package Manager` and installed the following packages related to `openconnect` which resolved the problem:

```
libopenconnect-dev (3.15-0ubuntu2)
network-manager-openconnect (0.9.4.0-0ubuntu1)
network-manager-openconnect-gnome (0.9.4.0-0ubuntu1)
```